# How do I install a Huion 1060+ on Loki?

Tags: release-loki, tablet

I need some help installing a Huion graphic tablet on Loki. elementary OS does have some wacom tablet settings, but when I plug my Huion, nothing happens — I mean, it reads its memory card, but when I move the pen over the workspace it doesn't affect the mouse pointer at all.

Edit#
Installing DEB package of DIGImend didn't help at all. Still same problem. Version of kernel I'm running is: 4.10.0-32-generic.

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking for can be found on the GitHub page for DIGImend which is here:

https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers

You can read through this page as it explains quite a bit in regards to drivers and such but notes there is an experimental DEB package. That DEB package can be found under the 'Releases' section of the page.

I have had experience with Wacom tablets and once I had the drivers installed I was good to go. Not sure if this will be the case here but it would be a good place to start.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: I've installed the DEB package, that changes nothing, cursor still doesn't move.

Comment: Your installation of the DEB package wasn't noted in the original question. It may be advantageous for you to edit your original question noting what you've done thus far to remedy the situation as that will be of great help towards troubleshooting and answers. Lastly, with what I've read, there seems to be compatability issues that arise depending upon what kernel a user is running. Please include your kernel version in the edit, too.

Comment: Sure thing, done that.